# The algebraic degree of a particular sum of algebraic numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $m$ be a positive integer. We know that $\beta:=p^{-1/m}$ is an $m$-degree algebraic number (in fact, its minimal polynomial is $pX^m-1$).

I would like to prove that the algebraic number
$$
\beta^{1!}+\beta^{2!}+\beta^{3!}+\cdots+\beta^{(m-1)!}
$$
has still degree $m$. Clearly, this number can be rewritten in the form
$$
r_0+r_1\beta+\cdots+r_{m-1}\beta^{m-1},
$$
where $r_0,\ldots,r_{m-1}$ are positive real numbers.

Maybe I can prove it using Galois conjugation, but I suppose that a much easier proof must do exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: With Galois theory this is, indeed, easy. If $L=\Bbb{Q}(\beta,\zeta_m)$ is the splitting field, and $\sigma$ is the generator of  $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}(\beta))$ determined by $\beta\mapsto \beta\zeta_m$, then the triangle inequality implies that the conjugates of the sum (call it $\gamma$) have either smaller absolute value, or are non-real. So $\gamma$ has at least $m$ distinct conjugates, all zeros of its minimal polynomial. Can't be more as $\gamma\in\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$.

Comment: Dear @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for your suggestion, however I was not able to follow it completely. Exactly in this part "then the triangle inequality implies that the conjugates of the sum (call it 
) have either smaller absolute value, or are non-real. So 
 has at least 
 distinct conjugates, all zeros of its minimal polynomial." I know a few on relation between the absolute values of conjugates and their distinctness. Could you please clarify it to me?

Comment: I seem to have jumped to some conclusions. The argument needs $px^m-1$ to remain irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. That is immediate, when $\gcd(m,\phi(m))=1$, and likely holds more generally. For example, when $p$ is unramified in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$. But I need to get a few things sorted out. Sorry.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks again. Actually I only need for p=10 (even that 10 is not prime). I am trying Galois conjugation but without success.